# converting variable to date format in unix script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, unix-timestamp

```
if [ -f $FILEPATH3 ]; then
#Will print the Header columns from properties file.
print $header >$CFILEPATH3
#To add rows in output file from input file .
awk -F\" 'BEGIN{OFS=FS;} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i=i+2){gsub(/,/,"~\t",$i);}}1' $FILEPATH3 > $TFILEPATH3

#Removes the footer,header and prints the columns as per mapping by picking column numbers from properties file 
cat $TFILEPATH3| sed '1d' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "~\t"; OFS = ",";}{ DATE = date -d "$'$ms2'" "+%Y%m%d" } { printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",  $'$ms1', $DATE,$'$ms3',$'$ms4',$'$ms5',$'$ms6',$'$ms7',$'$ms8’,”MS”,$’$ms10',$'$ms11',$'$ms12',$'$ms13',$'$ms14',$'$ms15',$'$ms16',$'$ms17'}' >> $CFILEPATH3
```

In the above code, I'm trying to copy the data from the input file to output file. ms1, ms2 are the column positions of a CSV input file.

ms2 is the date with format *mm/dd/yyyy* and which is considered as variable. We need to convert the variable into *YYYYMMDD* format and write it into output file

In the script I'm trying to change the date format to *YYYYMMDD*.. but I'm getting an error.

I think the error is from this code

```
{ DATE = date -d "$'$ms2'" "+%Y%m%d" }
```

Comment: in the properties file i have defined ms2=1 which means it has to pick the column 1 value from the input csv file. In input csv file, the column 1 will have date in the format of mm/dd/YYYY (example.. 6/03/2015).. i want to be formated to YYYYMMDD (20150603) while writing into output file..

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the variable in single quotes and which wont happen, So try to use the following syntax.

```
 DATE=$(echo $ms2|awk -F '/' '{print $3$2$1}')
cat $TFILEPATH3| sed '1d' | awk  -v ms2="$DATE" 'BEGIN { FS = "~\t"; OFS = ",";} { printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",  $'$ms1', $ms2,$'$ms3',$'$ms4',$'$ms5',$'$ms6',$'$ms7',$'$ms8’,”MS”,$’$ms10',$'$ms11',$'$ms12',$'$ms13',$'$ms14',$'$ms15',$'$ms16',$'$ms17'}' >> $CFILEPATH3
```

Comment: it did not work.. the output was   0$$ms2+%Y%m%d .. but i want the date

Comment: Can you please provide an example format and syntax of command that you are using?

Comment: ms2 is the date with format mm/dd/yyyy and which is considered as variable. We need to convert the variable into YYYYMMDD format and write it into output file

Comment: In that case you can use `awk` command to convert the variable.
`echo 'mm/dd/yyyy'|awk -F '/' '{print $3$1$2}'`

I modified the answer , You can refer that.

Comment: i tried.. it did not change the format.. it still prints the date as mm/dd/YYYY